# Cassandra data model to store embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, database-design, cassandra

In mongodb we can able to store embedded documents into a collection.Then, How do we store embedded documents into cassandra??? For this sample JSON representation???

```
UserProfile = {
name: "user profile",
Dave Jones: {
   email: {name: "email", value: "dave@email.com", timestamp: 125555555},
   userName: {name: "userName", value: "Dave", timestamp: 125555555}
},
Paul Simon: {
   email: {name: "email", value: "paul@email.com", timestamp: 125555555},
   phone: {name: "phone", value: "4155551212", timestamp: 125555555},
   userName: {name: "userName", value: "Paul", timestamp: 125555555}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your document nesting level is not too deep, you can use [User Defined Types](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1) from C* 2.1.

I personally suggest to rethink your schema into more flat form like:

`create table profiles (
  name text,
  name2 text,
  email text,
  username text,
  ts timestamp,
  primary key (name,name2) // compound primary key!
)`

Comment: Thanq, @shutty Iam also thinking the same,. Is it good to use user defined data types for 3 nesting levels????????